# static member with different values / instances

Tags: c++, oop, static-members

I worked the whole day to get some intsight into OOP in C++.
This might be stupid question and I guess it is just a knot in my head or a wrong design, but maybe you have an idea what to do.

I have a "top" class with a pointer array to a big bunch of "sub"-classes.
All "sub"-classes have some calculation to do and if they are finished they have to give a feedback to "top". So I thought make it simple use a static int "calculated"
and if everybody is finished it is 0.(else it is eg 1 or 5 depending on how many "sub"s are not calculated yet (e.g. after loading new raw datas)).

Ok so far so good, but what will happen if I want to speed up, make a new "top"-object with its own sub-objects, then they will all have the same static value(!). Of course I first tested it. Then I tried to make "sub" a private class of "top" (just an idea of a newbie). But no..., static is static and they all have the same values;)

I still have ideas, eg letting pointers in all "sub"s point to a member in top and then let them change it. This pointer would be different for different tops.

How ever I want to know if there is any "official" solution to assign different static values for different groups of objects (of one class).

BTW.: will it cause an error if sub access a private value of top via pointerarithmetics?

Greets from a newbie

benni

Comment: Why are you obsessed with `static`? It's just the wrong idea.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of relying on a `static` variable, make your subclasses know which parent do they belong to:

```
class sub;
class top{
   vector<sub*> subClasses;
public:
   void addSubClass(){ sub* ptr = new sub(this); }
   void subFinished(sub* child){ /* do whatever - perhaps delete from vector */ }
};

class sub{
   top *myParent;
public:
   void calculate(){ /* calculate something and let parent know */ myParent->subFinished(this); }
   sub(top* parent):myParent(parent){}

};
```

Answer (score 0):

First, don't make the counter static. If you want the value to be per instance of your "top" class, then make it just a regular member. static will make it one global variable for all instances of the top class.

Second, if "top" creates all the "sub" objects, when you create them, you can pass a reference (or pointer if you like) to the sub object on creation

```
class sub
{
public:
    explicit sub(int& counter) : m_counter(counter) {}

    void calc()
    {
        // do some stuff

        // decrement counter 
        --m_counter;
    }

private:
    int& m_counter;
};
```

OR, you could pass a reference to your top class into your sub class and the sub class can decrement the counter member directly or through a public member of your top class

```
class sub
{
public:
    explicit sub(top& t) : m_t(t) {}

    void calc()
    {
        // do some stuff

        // decrement counter 
        m_t.decrement();
    }

private:
    top& m_t;
};
```

You could also construct the sub classes and, after creation, set a pointer in the sub instance to either the counter variable or top instance but that isn't as safe as ensuring each instance of sub is initialized like my solutions above